# Difficulty in idenfying element using xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

On **www.cleartrip.com**

```
URL : https://www.cleartrip.com/flights/results?from=BOM&to=DEL&depart_date=17/03/2019&return_date=18/03/2019&adults=2&childs=0&infants=0&class=Economy&airline=&carrier=&intl=n&sd=1552380726320&page=loaded
```

I am trying to click on "Book" button and I am finding this element using xpath. But this xpath

> `//button[@type='submit' and @class='booking fRight']`

gives me two elements and the problem is these both elements have same html code, there is nothing unique between them. So my problem is how can I find correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a extra `<div>` with an id `ResultContainer_1_1` above the `Book` button that you are trying to click. So you can append that id in the xpath and then try to click on the button.
Please use the given below xpath, it should work for you:

```
WebElement bookButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ResultContainer_1_1']//button[@class='booking fRight']"));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this xpath it will return only one element

> //div[@id='ResultContainer_1_1']//button[@type='submit'][contains(text(),'Book')]